# Getting error: failed to download `solana-frozen-abi v1.9.9` while running anchor test on macbook m1

Tags: rust-cargo, solana, solana-web3js, anchor-solana, solana-cli

Guys while i was running anchor test on macbook m1, i am getting this error. Does anybody have a fix for this.

```
BPF SDK: /Users/dhruvjain/solana/bin/sdk/bpf
Running: rustup toolchain list -v
Running: cargo +bpf build --target bpfel-unknown-unknown --release
error: failed to download `solana-frozen-abi v1.9.9`

Caused by:
  unable to get packages from source

Caused by:
  failed to parse manifest at `/Users/dhruvjain/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/solana-frozen-abi-1.9.9/Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
  feature `edition2021` is required

  consider adding `cargo-features = ["edition2021"]` to the manifest
```

I found that i may have old rust or cargo version. But they seem to be up to date.

```
rustc 1.59.0 (9d1b2106e 2022-02-23)
```

Cargo Version

```
 cargo 1.59.0 (49d8809dc 2022-02-10)
```

I ran cargo clean but i still got the same error. Can somebody help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what solana version ?

```
solana -V
```

Ensure you are runnning `1.9.9`

```
sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/v1.9.9/install)"
```

Comment: I was using an old version of solana and that creating a problem. Thanks it got solved now.